# Rails 3.1 build GET form that creates a custom URL route that is SEO friendly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url-rewriting, form-submit

I would like to create custom SEO friendly routes similar to what is used by http://realestate.com.au For example the following page is shown by google when the search term *"real estate melbourne"* is used:

> *www.realestate.com.au/buy/in-melbourne,+vic+3000/list-1*

I would like use the following format. *mysite.com/trips/search/melbourne-to-sydney/01-01-2011*

I have configured the routes in my `routes.rb` file to get it to pick up the correct parameters when a url is entered is this format.

```
routes.rb
    match '/trips/search(/:fl(-to-:tl(/:tripdate)))' => 'trips#someaction'
```

My question is how do I setup a form in rails 3 to send a GET request using the above url structure. I have tried playing around with `to_params` though it seems to then change all my edit, show links etc which is not intended. I could build the link using javascript though I guess this would be a hacky option and the site would not work if javascript was disabled.

Is there a neat way to be able to create a GET submit form in Rails 3.1? The fields are select lists containing name and ids.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you immensely with the friendly URL portion

http://norman.github.com/friendly_id/file.Guide.html

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: Thanks for the answer Noli. I think this solution works well if the url can be determined on the server side (ie before the page has loaded).
What im looking to do, is create the url dynamically (via form GET request?). Im thinking javascript/jQuery may be the only way to do this, as i would like the url to be generated based on what the user selects from the form select lists (after page has loaded).
So url would be something like
http://0.0.0.0:3000/en/trips/search/[fromLocationName]-[toLocationName]

Comment: "Page does not exist!" for first page mentioned.